# Autoplay <audio> content from inactive tab/window?

Tags: html, audio, autoplay

Is it possible to tell  to audioplay an MP3 file when the tab or window isn't in focus? Basically, is there a way around making the tab active to start the audio, then resuming browsing in another tab?

I'm designing a multiple-page interactive website for a university project. The audio will play from one tab/window while the content pages display in another.

Answer (score 0):

Use this html

```
<audio controls autoplay="autoplay" id="audiotag">
    <source src="path to audio/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="path to audio/song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

and this javascript

```
document.getElementById('audiotag').play();
```

Comment: This works well in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: I think that is a problem caused by Quick Time. Check this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357196/audio-element-not-working-at-all-in-safari. Also check out this link https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html. Hope it will might help you.