# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function?

Tags: jquery, safari

In browser safari 5 we are get error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#testmusic").get(0).pause()')`

`$("#testmusic").get(0).pause()` used for stop music, full code player:

```
<audio id="testmusic" preload="auto" class="hide">
<source src="./music/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="./music/1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Why we are get this error and how to fix the error?
P.S.: chrome have not this error

Comment: Are sure jquery is included?

Comment: @AmmarCSE sure incude

Comment: may be `.get(0)` not need use in safari... ?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem because it does not give that error here https://jsfiddle.net/x3xu9wj5/

Comment: @Brown are you sure that the .mp3 is on place and plays correctly? I'll bet that the browser cannot find the .mp3 file for some reason (or is invalid).
That should explain why it does not work on Safari (.ogg not supported)

Comment: @AmmarCSE error was here http://i.imgur.com/WHjMYx4.png

Comment: @jpbalarini this cde work correctly in all browsers without safari. only safari see error in this code..

Comment: @Brown check removing the <source src="./music/1.ogg" type="audio/ogg"> and test it on chrome to see if it works. If it doesn't, you are having a problem with the .mp3 file.

Comment: @jpbalarini problem only in safari.

Comment: Is your code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @Barmar sure `$(function(){...});`

Comment: What does `console.log($("#testmusic").length)` show?

Comment: It sounds like Safari just doesn't have the `pause()` method.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but how stop music in safari ?

Comment: I can't explain why it doesn't work. https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW1 shows using `.pause()`.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357196/audio-element-not-working-at-all-in-safari